# Git is deleting every file open by any program. How do I fix it?

Tags: git, gitlab

The behavior I'm describing happens on all Windows 10 machines used by my team, that works on the same repo.

Essencially, whenever I I execute any Git command (`stash`, `pull`,`checkout`...) that requires Git to write a file, if that file is **open** by any program, Git will simply **delete** that file. Always. I work with `GitHub` for years and this never occurred. Now I'm working on a remote private `GitLab` repo. Not sure if this is related but the bug is absolutely annoyting.

It says:

> Unable to create/delete/modify file *: Permission denied.

Bang! Files deleted.

[image]

Basically Git is deleting files everytime it tries to touch an open file.

Basically, the only workaround is closing all my editors and terminals using any possible file before doing anything on Git everytime. Which I forget to do, which leads to files being deleted at least once a day.

Any idea how to fix this?

PS: OS: Windows 10. Git: 2.14.1.windows.1

Comment: This definitely sounds odd.  Are the files actually missing or just being reported as such (because of the permission denied error)?  You may want to report the issue to the Git for Windows maintainers in their [bug tracker](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues).  Note: Git will delete files if they're not present on the branch that you are switching to.  This is normal behavior if those files were under version control and didn't have any changes--but I think you probably know that already. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting your question right, whenever you execute a command (like stash, checkout) it changes the state of your code directory, right? Of course, it would, that's the purpose of git to change working directory according to the current branch (excluding the untracked files of course).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but no.. I`m saying that whenever git needs to modify a file opened by any software, Git deletes the file. It`s not like I`m trying to delete the file.. The diles aren't supposed to be deleted

Comment: Have you tried checking and fixing the permissions.

Comment: What do you mean by fixing the permissions?

Comment: @andrerpena You need to have write permissions for all the files in your project directory.

Comment: I have, otherwise closing the applications that have that file open, like Visual Studio Code, would not make the problem to go away. And I know Visual Sudio Code doesn't lock files. I can delete files open by VS Code. It's a git bug/problem

Comment: @andrerpena if Visual Studio doesn't do something with file permissions, then how does git even knows that file is open, and messes stuff up? Have you tried another editor just to test?

Comment: Well. This is a good question. And yes, this problem occurs with VS Code, VS, WebStorm and Node.js (these apps locking the file). @hspandher, I appreciate your help. I'll try to debug this problem later

Comment: @anderpena Glad to be no help, I'm afraid. :)